# Pandas Dataframe merge with partial value overlap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to figure out how to vectorize a merging of data based on a partial comparison of values between dataframes:

Say I have some data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Abe', 'AA01', '40'],
                   ['Bill', 'AA02', '42'],
                   ['Carly', 'BB01', '43'],
                   ['Debbie', 'BB02', '44'],
                   ['Edward', '', '45']],
                   columns=['name', 'id', 'age'])

     name    id age
0     Abe  AA01  40
1    Bill  AA02  42
2   Carly  BB01  43
3  Debbie  BB02  44
4  Edward        45
```

And then I have data containing some meta data about ids:

```
meta = pd.DataFrame([['AA', 'Alpha Apples'],
                     ['BB', 'Beta Bananas']],
                     columns=['id-prefix', 'group'])

  id-prefix         group
0        AA  Alpha Apples
1        BB  Beta Bananas
```

So a 'group' is determined by a comparison between id and id-prefix.
How do I merge this information idiomatically and performantly?

I wrote something like this:

```
df['group'] = ''
for row in meta.values:
    id_prefix, group = row
    df.loc[df.id.str.startswith(id_prefix), 'group'] = group
```

Which results in the correct data:

```
     name    id age         group
0     Abe  AA01  40  Alpha Apples
1    Bill  AA02  42  Alpha Apples
2   Carly  BB01  43  Beta Bananas
3  Debbie  BB02  44  Beta Bananas
4  Edward        45
```

But it is not very performant on large dataframes and it seem that looping of dataframes is usually the wrong solution and is discouraged.

What would be a better way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be faster than your method . You can add `.fillna('')` at the end

```
df['group']=df.id.str[:2].map(meta.set_index('id-prefix')['group'])
df
Out[415]: 
     name    id age         group
0     Abe  AA01  40  Alpha Apples
1    Bill  AA02  42  Alpha Apples
2   Carly  BB01  43  Beta Bananas
3  Debbie  BB02  44  Beta Bananas
4  Edward        45           NaN
```

Comment: That's great thank you :) However what if id-prefix is not always 2 character wide? I know that's what it is like in the example but it is not always that in all data.

Comment: @genuinelycurious you can look at `str.extract`

Comment: @genuinelycurious something like `df['id'].str.extract('([A-z]+)').map(meta.set_index('id-prefix')['group'])`